# Custom background color flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, sapui5

I want to set background color on flexbox and tried as follow.

Class definition on app:

```
<App id="app" class="weight-protocol"></App>
```

on FlexBox:

```
  <FlexBox
      height="20%"
      width="100%"
      alignItems="Start"
      class="calendar-header-bg"
      justifyContent="Center">
```

in the css file:

```
.weight-protocol .calendar-header-bg {
    background-color: #007DB2;
}
```

The custom background color is not going to apply at all as you can see:
[image]

Look at the code inspector, the custom css class stays at the beginning `calendar-header-bg` instead at last.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try without `.weight-protocol` ?

```
.calendar-header-bg {
    background-color: #007DB2;
}
```

If not work you can use `!important` tag:

```
.calendar-header-bg {
    background-color: #007DB2 !important;
}
```

You can also try use only `background` tag instead `background-color`:

```
.calendar-header-bg {
    background: #007DB2 !important;
}
```

I hope this helps...

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't FlexBox have some css to do what you are trying to achieve? use inspector and watch for the div that cointains the flexbox.
Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the problem is specificity also known as importance of selectors. This means that the selector you're using (class nested in class) has little weight overall, and it very likely overwritten by a different, heavier selector from within the library you're using. For instance the library might be targeting a class within a class within an id or something similar.

My advice is to see the applied styles within the dev tools, see what's overwriting your styles and then decide if you'll make your selector stronger( by making it more specific) or just add `!important` after your `background-color` declaration.